# Internal server error Azure Functions with spfx react-search-refiners

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-language-understanding, spfx, azure-function-app-proxy

I am deploying react-search-refiner with LUIS and Azure Functions https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-search-refiners/functions

Now, I passed through various problems and finally confirmed the communication from SPFx to Function App.

My problem is when searching after deploying according to the procedure, an internal Sever error occurs after Status Code 200. And nothing error message returns.

> POST https://.azurewebsites.net/api/enhanceQuery 500
>   (Internal Server Error) Message: [NlpService.enhanceSearchQuery()]:
>   Error: '{"error":{"type":"function_error","message":"Error"}}' for url
>   'https://.azurewebsites.net/api/enhanceQuery'

On the application log, Function App is executed and succeeded return code 0. So, it doesn't return error code.

My checking is below that does not contains in README. Would someone help me?

- Set local.settings.json to environment variable.
- Change authlevel "function" to "anonymous" for simplization.
- Local debug is succeeded.
- POSTMAN didn't check because rawQuery from HttpRequest might be
  included large keys and values.

Comment: Why not test the function with POSTMAN?

Comment: I fall test because I don't confirm enough information to test yet. e.g luisAuthoringKey, required value of HttpRequest.